# I am using the following code to select from a MySQL database with a Code Igniter webapp:

Tags: codeigniter

```
$query = $this->db->get_where('mytable',array('id'=>10));
```

This works great! But I want to write the following MySQL statement using the CI library?

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `id`='10' OR `field`='value'
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried or_where()?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325906/7708344 This answer is helpful. Thanks @Rahi

Answer (score 0):

Using codeigniter's query builder, you can do the following to generate your query.

```
$this->db->where('id'=>10)->or_where('field'=>'value')->get('mytable');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$this->db->where(['id'=>10])->or_where(['field'=>'value'])->get('mytable');
```